# Alternando estados de uma aplicação js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, react, electron

### INTRODUÇÃO

Estou desenvolvendo um app usando Electron e o google maps, preciso controlar o estado de uma das janelas, por exemplo: o usuário clica no botão  e apartir deste momento todo clique dele no mapa adiciona um marcador.

Bom o problema está em controlar os estados, tentei chegar a alguma solução, fui atras de tutoriais, bibliotecas como react e/ou frameworks como angular 1, 2, também cai em um frame work chamado Choo  mas no final das contas não cheguei a conclusão alguma, só fiquei mais confuso em como fazer.

### MINHA SOLUÇÃO

Para começar, vou apresentar minha primeira tentativa de ‘solução’ com base neste [TUTORIAL](http://robdodson.me/take-control-of-your-app-with-the-javascript-state-patten/), no qual fiz algumas mudanças.

```js
function machine () {
  this.estadoatual = undefined;
  const estados = {
    estado1:  {
      log:() => {console.log('teste')}
      /*funçoes e comandos do estado*/
    },
    estado2:  {
      log:() => {console.log('teste2')}
      /*funçoes e comandos do estado*/
    }
    /*...*/
  };

  this.changeState = (string) => {
    //verifica a string e o estado atual
    if ( string == 'estado1' && this.estadoatual !== estados.estado1) {
      this.estadoatual = estados.estado1;
    }
    //verifica a string e o estado atual
    if ( string == 'estado2' && this.estadoatual !== estados.estado2) {
      this.estadoatual = estados.estado2;
    }
  }
  
  
}

const teste = new machine();

/* por favor abra o console :P */
teste.changeState('estado1');
teste.estadoatual.log();
teste.changeState('estado2');
teste.estadoatual.log();
```

Nessa solução todos os estados teriam de ter as mesmas propriedades para que fossem executados de forma correta, mas isso resultaria em um monte de outras funções resultantes de cada objeto, como:  teste.estadoatual.render(), teste.estadoatual.deleteRender() e por ai vai, com essa quantidade de funções fica tudo mais confuso.

Pensei em uma segunda solução para meu problema:

```js
function machine () {
  this.estadoatual = undefined; 
  const self = this;
  
  function estado1 () {    
    console.log('executou o estado1');
    function log () {console.log('click estado1')};// função chamada no evento de click bt1    
    $('#bt1').bind('click', log);
    $('#bt2').bind('click', (event) => {
    self.changestate('estado2');
    $('#bt1').unbind('click', log);
    $(this).unbind(event);  
    })
    this.log = () => {console.log('estado1')}; 
  }
  
  function estado2 () {
    console.log('executou o estado2');
    function log () {console.log('click estado2')};// função chamada no evento de click bt1    
    $('#bt1').bind('click', log);
    $('#bt2').bind('click', (event) => {
    self.changestate('estado1');
    $('#bt1').unbind('click', log);
    $(this).unbind(event);  
    })
    this.log = () => {console.log('estado2')}; 
  }  
  
  this.changestate = (string) => {
   if(string == 'estado1')  { 
/* neste caso não sei como fazer a verificação para não reiniciar o valor do 'estadoatual' quando o usuario clicar de novo*/
     this.estadoatual = new estado1();     
     }
      if(string == 'estado2')  {
/* neste caso não sei como fazer a verificação para não reiniciar o valor do 'estadoatual' quando o usuario clicar de novo*/
     this.estadoatual = new estado2();       
     }
  }
}

const teste = new machine();

//Inicializa o app no estado1
//neste caso ele é quase todo contido em si , não necessitando de chamadas externas, mas também não descartando elas.
teste.changestate('estado1');
//consigo chamar funções que podem ser acessadas fora do escopo da função.
teste.estadoatual.log();
```

```css
.bt{
height: 30px;
 width: 50px;  
}

#bt1{
background-color: red;
}


#bt2{
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='bt1' class='bt'></div>
<div id='bt2' class='bt'></div>
```

O código acima funciona de certa forma ... bem, o botão vermelho executa o log, e o azul troca de estado, mas não consigo verificar qual estado ele está pra evitar que o usuário fique "spammando" o botão e o app bugue, o que seria péssimo, nesse caso isso não acontece mas quando ele receber um comando de um botão que esta contido em outra janela, o usuário pode simplesmente ficar apertando e re-iniciando o código.

### DUVIDAS

**EDIT: as perguntas, são de certa forma individuais, não sei se é permitido algo assim, mas se tiver a resposta para alguma delas, por favor, compartilhe conosco**

1. Como posso fazer a verificação do estado no segundo exemplo? Algo semelhante a verificação da primeira solução. **<<< RESOLVIDO (LER RESPOSTA E EDITS).**
2. Há alternativas a esse design? Se sim, quais você conhece e quais recomenda?
3. Com a minha pesquisa, vi que frameworks como angular e o Choo lidam com o estado da aplicação, há mais alternativas a eles?
4. Qual a vantagem de usar frameworks ao invés do método que estou usando?
5. O React também lida com estados, mas qual a diferença deles para o angular ou Choo?

### BIBLIOGRAFIA

**Tutorial state pattern:** http://robdodson.me/take-control-of-your-app-with-the-javascript-state-patten/
**Choo:** https://github.com/yoshuawuyts/choo
**Angular:** https://angular.io/
**React:** https://facebook.github.io/react/
**Electron:**http://electron.atom.io/

### EDITS

Depois de um pouco mais de esforço, cheguei a uma resposta que reage como desejo, segue a resposta:

```js
function machine() {
  const self = this;
  
  this.estadoatual = undefined;
  let estadoatual = undefined;
  let estados = [];


  this.addstate = (obj) => {
   estados.push(obj);
    console.log('[STATE_MACHINE]> '+ obj.name + ' <added to states!');
  };

  this.changestate = (string) => {
 for(var i in estados) {
     if(string == estados[i].name) {
          console.log('[STATE_MACHINE] Found: ' + estados[i].name);
          if(string !== estadoatual){
            console.log('[STATE_MACHINE] State changed to: ' + estados[i].name + '.');
            estadoatual = estados[i].name;
            self.estadoatual = new estados[i].constructor;
       }
      }
    }
  }

}    

const sm = new machine();
//Note que o objeto leva somente dois parametros, na função construtora, pode se escrever o que desejar.
sm.addstate({name:'nome', constructor: function(){
  console.log('teste');
}});

sm.changestate('nome');
```

Comment: Essa temática é muito interessante mas a tua pergunta são 4 em 1 e assim fica difícil de responder... Podes "partir isso" em perguntas diferentes? Ou uma a seguir à outra para ter uma sequência talvez...

Comment: Bom... a sequencia seria mais ou menos a que está na parte de duvidas :P mas posso tentar defini-las melhor

Comment: obrigado :P estou a uns bons dias atras da resposta...

Comment: Oi Joao. Você pode postar sua resposta abaixo, na área de respostas? Ficou estranho ter a resposta como parte da pergunta.

Comment: depois que eu terminar de fazer alguns ajustes eu coloco sim

Comment: @JoaoScheuermann não te esqueças de colocar a resposta em baixo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### RESPOSTA:

Após algum esforço, cheguei a uma resposta definitiva, agora também sei que há muitas outras formas de se chegar a esse resultado e maneiras de modificar meu codigo para funcionar de outras formas, com hooks para cada transição ou coisa do tipo.

Mas direto a resposta.

```js
// STATE MACHINE
function machine() {
    const self = this;

    let ea = undefined;
    let estadoatual = undefined;
    let estados = [];

    //Adiciona um estado se não houver um com mesmo nome
    function addstate(obj) {
        let found_state = false;
        for (var i in estados) {
            if (estados[i].name == obj.name) {
                found_state = true;
                //console.warn(`[STATE_MACHINE] You already have ${obj.name} state stored`);
                return
            }
        }
        if (found_state == false) {
            estados.push(obj);
            //console.log(`[STATE_MACHINE]> ${obj.name} <added to states!`);
        }
    }


    this.addstate = (obj) => {
        addstate(obj);
    };
    
    //Troca o estado e chama as funçoes onChange quando mudar de estado e onOpen quando entrar em um estado.
    function changeState(string) {
        for (var i in estados) {
            if (string == estados[i].name) {
                //console.log(`[STATE_MACHINE] Found: ${estados[i].name}`);
                if (string !== estadoatual) {
                    if (ea !== undefined) {
                        ea.onChange();
                    }
                    //console.log('[STATE_MACHINE] State changed to: ' + estados[i].name + '.');
                    estadoatual = estados[i].name;
                    ea = new estados[i].constructor();
                    ea.onOpen()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    this.changestate = (string, param) => {
        changeState(string, param);
    }

}
```

Basicamente temos dois métodos, "addstate" e "changestate", ao chamar o addstate, você terá de passar um objeto contendo o metodo 'name' e um contendo uma função construtora ('contructor'), essa função terá dois métodos, onOpen e onChange, que serão chamados respectivamente quando um estado for aberto ou quando ele for trocado. Segue um exemplo de inicialização do código.

```js
const sm = new machine();

//Note que o objeto leva somente dois parametros, na função construtora, deve-se passar os parametros onOpen e onChange...

//Adiciona um estado:
sm.addstate({name:'FOO', constructor: function(){
  this.onOpen = () => {
    //Codigo para ser executado quando aberto.
  }
  this.onChange = () => {
    //Codigo para ser executado quando for trocado por outro estado.
  }
}});
```

Agora que já criamos uma maquina de estados e adicionamos um, é só chamar o método sm.changestate('Foo').

```js
// Faz a troca de estados.
sm.changestate('FOO');
```

Com isso cheguei a resposta que desejava, o código funciona de forma assincrona, não necessitando de uma ordem para ser ativado apenas  chamar o método changestate(). Algumas das outras perguntas continuam sem resposta e eu gostaria muito de que alguém pudesse me ajudar com elas...